# Spring task executor in jboss

Tags: spring, jboss

I am currently using spring task executor framework in jboss as 7 (I am not using java ee features of jboss, I use only servlets) and my configuration looks like below

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="${async.threadPoolSize}"
    queue-capacity="${async.queueCapacity}" />
```

When jboss is started how does spring manage the thread pools, would it become unmanaged from jboss perspective or would the thread pool be created from a pool configured in standalone.xml  allocated to jboss web ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is going to create a *standalone* thread poll (i.e. "unmanaged" from JBoss).

Hooking up a thread poll on AS7 is tricky as explained in the [Javadoc of JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/work/jboss/JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor.html)